# Swift - After closing and open view again array is always reset

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have two views. In first one is a button in the NavBar that opens another view. In that view is a textfield and button that adds the data of the textfield into an array. The button also closes the view. When I reopen the view again and add another entry in that array it overrides the first entry. I can't get more than one entry in that array. I open the view over storyboard and close it programmatically.

```
var categoryArray = [String]()


@IBAction func createCategoryTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

if categoryNameTextField.text?.isEmpty == false {


    let addCategory = categoryNameTextField.text

    categoryArray.append(addCategory!)

    // schließt das View
    navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)


    } else {

        // else....
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling both `popViewController` and `dismiss`? Only call the one you actually need.

Comment: When you create a new instance of the view controller, it gets its own new set of property values. Why would the new controller's array have values from the old, long gone controller's array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

categoryArray gets nil when you pop view controller.